# Jquery autocomplete - how to add on click event to the list

Tags: jquery

HI i am using the below code for population my autocomplete list.

```
    $('#input').autocomplete({ ajax_get : get_roles});

    function get_roles(v,cont,roleName){
            var roleName = roleName.value;
            roleName = roleName.toLowerCase();
            $.get('/da/roleautocomplete?roleName='+escape(roleName),{q:v},
                function(obj){
                  var res = [];
                  for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
                    res.push({ id:i , value:obj[i]});
                  }
                  cont(res);
                },
                'json')
        }
```

I want to fire an event on the click or selection of an item from the autocomplete list. I have tried this -

```
$('#input').autocomplete({
     select:function(event, ui){
          // do your things here
      }, etc.
```

but to no avail. Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: I don't know how to "accept", which link to click , how to vote for a good answer? Can someone please tell?

Comment: If you look at the answers to your questions, there are numbers with up-down arrows in the upper left of the answer.  Directly beneath that is an icon that looks like a check.  The title attribute text for those control elements explains how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem when first trying to use `select:function(event,ui){ ... }`, but it is definitely the way to go.

The key is to use `ui.item` to get ahold of the option that was clicked or otherwise selected.  I had originally been using `event` then `this`, but those are different for clicks vs key select (take a look with `console.log` for some perspective), so `ui.item` is what you want.  The autocomplete will be setting `label: ..., value: ...`, so most likely what you'll use are `ui.item.label` and `ui.item.value`.

Answer (score 2):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/DMDHC/

Helpful read: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ (you can read about options and events available etc.)

**Code:**

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( req, resp ) {
        $.post( "/echo/json/", {
            json: '["Rambo", "Foobar", "This", "That", "Batman", "Hulk"]',
            delay: 1
        }, function(data) {
            resp( data );
        }, "JSON" );
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var TABKEY = 9;
        this.value = ui.item.value;

        if (event.keyCode == TABKEY) { 
            event.preventDefault();
            this.value = this.value + " ";
            $('#search').focus();
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: In my code if put the above select function it just doesn't call the function written in the select tag. Please help !

Comment: @linusunisfed can you make you changes in the jsfiddle and flick it to me **or** it seems you got the answer from the post above <as I can see green arrow poping> anyhow have fun! :)

Comment: Actually i am using a different plugin. That's jquery.js and Autocomplete.js which is some jqac plugin. The plugin what you are using is probably different. Please let me know !

Comment: Hiya @linusunisfed hmm no worries bruv :) it doesn't seem like but can you flick me the url of the page from where you are using your plugin please & its very late at my side of the globe so I will sleep in 10 /20 mins :) let me know which plugin you are using, have a nice one, cheers!

Comment: I am using the below plugin - http://code.google.com/p/jqac/issues/attachmentText?id=1&aid=8783728231022238274&name=jquery.autocomplete.js&token=9dnMDB7EtoiQfr5l3csyY-lciZw%3A1332856261813

Comment: @linusunisfed bro if I may suggest use the one I shared a link above in my paste, see the plugin you are using is not even updated for long since 2008 I reckon is I am not wrong : http://code.google.com/p/jqac/downloads/list & example page doesn't seem to be working here: http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~ygleyzer/files/utils/jqac/jqac_example.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10845/discussion-between-linusunis-fed-and-tats-innit)